# Re-generate world as a Biomes O' Plenty world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Okay, so I did a bad thing. I set up a new Minecraft world, and I've spend about 3-4 hours getting everything set up, now I'm ready to explore, but I realize I've left level-type as default.

Is there anyway (I have MCedit if that's useful), to re-generate my world using Biomes O' Plenty, but keep any blocks I've places? I've not done much digging so I don't care if that resets, but my hourse, chests, farms etc I'd like to keep if possible.

Worst comes to the worst I can maybe move my base to a currently unloaded area, which I'd rather not but if it would work that would be good.

Comment: I'm not by any means a minecraft expert but maybe this works. If you (can) move buildings from one map to another using MCedit you can create the new map with the correct level-type. Copy your buildings with MCedit from your old map to your new map.

Comment: Good idea, if nothing else comes up I'll give that a try.

Comment: You could try changing the world generator settings in your `level.dat`. (I don't know the exact name world-type, but it's definitely not `NORMAL`) This means all future chunks will/may (if it is set to 100% change that it'll not be a Vanilla biome) be Biome O' Plenty biomes.

Comment: You can also take your character folder from the generated world directory, then generate a world with Biomes O' Plenty enabled and paste your character folder there. Ofcourse your base would be gone but you can take most of the machines with you in your inventory.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing Marco Geertsma's idea. Here's what I did

1. Stored everything I had
2. Logged off
3. When into my players folder, and backed up `{YourUsername}.dat`
4. Regenerated my world
5. **Logged in without restoring my character** so I could get the coords for world spawn, as the .dat file seemed to contain my coords too.
6. Replaced the .dat file with my backup
7. Logged in and teleported to the world spawn coords.
8. Rebuilt my house, and off I go!

I also used a different world seed, but you could easily just keep it the same.

Something I cheated at to make it easier for me, was I got a couple of Strongboxes to store all my items, and I could only carry about a third of my items at once.