# I downloaded the create mod in minecraft in a world that's already generated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I downloaded the Create mod in minecraft in a world that's already generated and there are new ores in the mod. What can i do to make the ores show without harming my builds?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will new Minecraft features appear in existing worlds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28801/will-new-minecraft-features-appear-in-existing-worlds)

Comment: Although it is a duplicate, this seems like a gameplay issue rather than a technical issue, so the close vote for "Technical support for modded minecraft" is incorrect.

Comment: @pppery i dont think its a duplicate bc the duplicate implies updates being the issue and while this is similar I think itd be best to keep it separate

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Installing mods is not different at all from updating the game in this respect, and in fact [I need help with the minecraft dinosaur mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/222490/185203), which this is a more direct duplicate of, was closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Also an even more direct duplicate of [Re-generate world as a Biomes O' Plenty world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/187970/185203)

Answer (score 0):

There are three main methods to doing this. First, travel to new chunks. Second, delete old chunks, and make them regenerate. Third, manually place the ores in creative.

First method is travelling to new chunks. Fairly self explanatory. Easiest way to do that is with an elytra, second is getting a boat on a big ocean. Fastest way to do that is getting a dolphin on a lead, and using depth strider. More is explained here:

.

Second, is delete old chunks. You could use WorldEdit or MCEdit. This will delete any builds in the chunks, and then minecraft will make the chunk like new again, so the ores will generate in it.

Third is just placing the ores in creative. You could get a friend to do it for you, so you don't know where all the ores are. You might also come up with a creative way to give yourself the minerals, such as a minigame, or other. If you don't have cheats on in your world, don't worry, as you can just open it to lan, enable cheats, and suddenly you have cheats too (temporarily)